# Generic subtype inheritance

Tags: c#

i want to define "Hayt" class constraint for "hede" method.

is there a way for define constraint like

```
Hayt<?> or Hayt<extends Huyt>
```

this is the test code

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hayt<Huyt> asd1 = new Hayt<Huyt>();
            Hayt<Huyt2> asd2 = new Hayt<Huyt2>();

            //there arent any problem here
            hede<Hayt<Huyt>>(asd1);

            //runtime error
            hede<Hayt<Huyt2>>(asd2);
        }

        static T hede<T>(T vede)
            where T : Hayt<Huyt>
        {
            return vede;
        }
    }

    public class Hayt<T>
        where T : Huyt

    {

    }

    public class Huyt
    {

    }

    public class Huyt2 : Huyt
    {

    }
```

and its possible like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Hayt<Huyt> asd1 = new Hayt<Huyt>();
    Hayt<Huyt2> asd2 = new Hayt<Huyt2>();

    hede<Hayt<Huyt>, Huyt>(asd1);

    hede<Hayt<Huyt2>, Huyt2>(asd2);
}

static T hede<T, B>(T vede)
    where B : Huyt
    where T : Hayt<B>
{
    return vede;
}
```

but i think there are probably better off solution

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What exactly is your goal and what is your problem?

Comment: And who are Hayt and Huyt? :-)

Comment: @Vitaliy it's Turkish for Foo and Baz

Comment: @dbaseman: What about Bar? Doesn't he get to be turkish?

Comment: you should use meaningfull names, it is very hard to understand the logic by looking at "Hayt" "Huyt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you'd do. There is no smoother method.

Note though, that C# 4.0 adds co-variance and contra-variance to the mix. See e.g.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Comment: how these working on .net 3.5? i have tried .net 3.5 project and it worked :/

Comment: hmm im recognized .net features and c# features are different things right now. am i right?

Comment: Indeed the language spec has independent versioning, although I'm pretty sure that Framework v4 is required to actually use co/contravariance in generics